# Problem in fetching data from API in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I want to add the data which I get from API in my list, but the list is not adding or shows null.

```
final List<Result> _futureData = [];

final List<Result> books = [];


  Future<void> showAllData() async {
    final url = 'https://gutendex.com/books?topic=${widget.Subject}';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      
      final List body = jsonDecode(response.body)['results'];
      setState(() {
        for (var y in body) {
          Result res = Result.fromJson(y);
          _futureData.add(res);
        }
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch books from API');
    }
  }
```

Here, I have a list of Result object where the `jsondata` that I get from API will be initially a dynamic list type and then with each iteration I was converting to model class object and then adding to the list. But  the debug console shows that the list is empty and null. So , how can i add the data in the list that I get from this API.

Error is the list shows empty.

Comment: What gets displayed on printing response.body?

Comment: response.body is working fine the dynamic list is showing. But when i am tryin to iterate and add each map object in list its not working and at the end it shows list is null or empty